# Show that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^n}$ converges for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ outside $|1+z^2|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

**Show that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^n}$ converges for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ outside $|1+z^2|=1$**

Actually, I have the problem to understand the meaning of "outside $|1+z^2|=1$". If it means that the collection of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|1+z^2|>1.$ This problem will be easy to verify since for each given $z$ with $|1+z^2|>1$, then we have $|1+z^2|^{-1}<1$. Then, it is the geometric series with common ratio less than $1$ which implies that the series converges.

Do I have correct interpretation with "outside $|1+z^2|=1$"? If not, what is the correct interpretation with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this has to be the correct way to interpret it. But it's certainly unclear to phrase it like that. Worse, if you draw $\{ z:\lvert z^2+1 \rvert=1 \}$, you discover that it's actually a figure-8 shape that divides the plane into three regions (so "outside" is the unbounded bit?). Much better to say "when $z$ is not in $\{z:\lvert z^2+1 \rvert \leqslant 1\}$", or "when $ \lvert z^2+1 \rvert>1$" which are completely unambiguous.